# What will happen in night of devatas?

Tags: time, devatas

In night time of devatas do creation will there .
What devatas will do in night time.
What will happen to creation in night time of devatas.

Answer (score 4):

There is no night or day for devatas. Brahma’s day and night is figurative

> This period is called the night of god Brahma. The creation of the
> universe is called his day. **Really, there is neither day nor night of
> Brahma. This is used in a figurative sense.**

**Kurma Purana I.4.11**

> The period of the duration of the Prakrita creation is said to be a
> day of Brahma. There is a similar period constituting the night. The
> Lord effects creation during day time and dissolution during the
> night. **He had neither a day nor a night (as we understand the terms).
> The time-duration by day and night is used in the secondary sense.**

**Linga Purana I.4.1-2**

The universe remains in an unmanifested state during the 'night'.

Comment: "There is no night or day for devatas" - couldn't understand this.. "The southern Ayana is a night, and the northern a day of the gods" ~ [Vishnu Purana: Book I: Chapter III](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm)... The period from Karka Sankranti to Makar Sankranti is known as the southern Ayana (Dakshinayana) i.e. night of gods and Makar Sankranti to Karka Sankranti as northern Ayana (Uttarayana) i.e. day, right?..

Comment: Doesn't ayana mean path? Dakshinayan means the southern path of the sun  and Uttarayana means the northern path of the sun. At least this what I think.

Comment: yeah..but the duration which Dakshinayan/Uttarayana takes is night/day for gods..[Kurma Purana 1.5.9](https://archive.org/details/kurma-purana-full-parts-1-and-2/page/48/mode/1up) is also in sync with Vishnu Purana..i think u hv provided references for Brahama not for devas..